# SSL certificate change e private.key

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, private-key

I need help in the following situation:

My company renewed the SSL certificate, and I need to change it in server IIS.
The file that the certifier sent is a **.crt**, and as the server is windows I believe that for installation it must be a **.pfx**
So far so good, I thought of converting via openssl using the command below:

**openssl pkcs12 –export –out certificate.pfx –inkey rsaprivate.key –in certificate.crt –certfile fileca.crt**

The problem is that I don't have the .key file
In contact with the certifier, she informed that because it is a renewal, the .key is the same used in the first installation, only that the team that did the first installation is no longer in the company, and we did not find the .key file in no repository.

My question is:

Would there be any way to convert to .pfx without the .key? or would it be possible to find out the .key already used before?
Does anyone have any idea what can be done in this case?

Comment: It must be there, or you couldn't have been using TLS/SSL before you renewed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate the private key of the .crt file.  If you could, the internet would be completely insecure!

Since the certificate is a renewal, you should already have the provider root/intermediary certificate installed on your system.

Convert your .crt file to .cer using openssl.

Then in IIS, click "Complete Certificate Request", and navigate to your newly create .cer file and import.

Then you need to bind your new certificate to your website...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback.
A great tip, I'll try to do it and come back to tell you how it went.

Just ask me a doubt please, the current certificate is still valid.
As I don't have a laboratory to test it, if I carry out the procedure of importing the newly converted "Complete Certificate Request"
Could it have any impact on the already installed certificate?

My idea would be to import the new, keep both (old and new), and link the new. If it was ok I'll keep it, if not I'll link the old one again.

Comment: You should be able to import both.  Which certificate is used depends on which one you select to bind to your website...

Comment: OK, I'll do the test and get back.

Again thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I did the procedure for converting .crt to .cer as follows:

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/361/17/how-do-i-convert-crt-file-into-the-microsoft-cer-format

The conversion completes without errors.
When I go into IIS and select > "Complete Certificate Request"
and I try to import, it reports the error:

Details:

The requested property value is empty. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80094004)

And it doesn't matter the certificate.

Comment: Can you verify you have the provider of the certificate in your root certificate store or intermediate certificate store?

Comment: Friend, coming back here to give feedback.
It all worked out with a friend's tip.
I was wrong. CA sent the .crt file but was the intermediary.
the certificate file was in .txt format and I hadn't logged on.
After converting the .txt to .cer and following the friend's tip, everything went well.

Thank you very much.